# Unable to send Token in Dot Net Core API from Console App

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new in .Net Core Application, I have created .Net Core API and calling these APIs from Console App, I am able to login and get the Token as well.

now when I want to pass this token for next call I am getting Unauthorize Error.

```
public void GetEmployeesByToken()
    {
        try
        {
            string str = string.Empty;

            string url = baseUrl + "api/Employees/GetEmployees";

            using (HttpClient webRequest = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "Get";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                //request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + BearerToken;
                webRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",  BearerToken);
                //webRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", BearerToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = webRequest.GetAsync(url).Result;
                //webRequest.GetAsync().Result;
                
                if (response != null)
                {
                    //str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I tried multiple way but still same issue.

below is my controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetEmployees")]
    public List<string>GetEmployees()
    {
        return new List<string>() {"Employee01", "Employee02", "Employee03", "Employee04", "Employee05"};
    }
```

BearerToken I am setting in response of login request.

below code in Startup.cs class for dot net core API

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();

        //For Entity Framework
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStr")));

        //For Identity
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        //Adding Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })

        //Addding Jwt Bearer
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
            };
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPI_First", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "WebAPI_First v1"); //originally "./swagger/v1/swagger.json"
            });
            //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPI_First v1"));
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Login method when I am able to call and get the JWT token

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if(user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var AuthClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                AuthClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

            var authSignKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_Configarion["JWT:Secret"]));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _Configarion["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _Configarion["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: AuthClaims,
                signingCredentials : new SigningCredentials(authSignKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo,
                user = user.UserName
            }); ;
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does the login account have the `UserRoles.Admin` role?

Comment: yes he has admin role, even I tried with normal authorization attribute same error

Comment: In that case it all looks fine, perhaps you can provide a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Since Morning I am stuck, so thought to put my question here. I have added startup class code as well if something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetEmployeesByToken(string token)
{
......
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
    string uri = "api/Employees/GetEmployees";

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    
   var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(stringData);
     return result;
        
    }
return null;
}
```

if it still doesn't work then you will have to post the startup file and the code you have used to create the token.

Update:

try to add  app.UseAuthentication() before UseAuthorization

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: same error

{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 10:26:43 GMT
}, Trailing Headers:
{
}}

Comment: @MohanChandra try to add  app.UseAuthentication() before UseAuthorization

Comment: Thank you so much, I missed app.UseAuthentication(); now I added and it is working as expected. Thanks a lot for your help. Please add this two line code in your above solution with comment so I can mark it as solution.